# Receive the multiple message socket programming C

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

Hi I new to socket programming C. Now I working on chat program and I successful can sending and receiving message but the problem is when client request to send list of user that client online and once server send message back to client the message is successful print the list of current connected client but once it display it not going out of loop. below is only one section of the code.

server side (server.c)

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&list_mutex);
   for(i =0; i < NotEndOfList; i++)
   {

    sprintf(message_replay, "Server: %s \n", usersList[i].name); 
    write(sock , message_replay , strlen(message_replay));  

  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&list_mutex);
```

Client side (Client.c)

```
int i =0;
          while(i < NotEndOfList)
         {
            if( recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
            {
              puts("recv failed");
              break;
            }
         i++;

        puts(server_reply);
      }
```

Sample Output

```
    User A -->:
    //List 
    User A
    User B
    User C
    // Loop
```

Correct Sample Output

```
User A -->:
//List
User A
User B
User C
User A -->:
```

Thank you very much

Comment: There is no guarantee that each call to `write` in the server will result in that entire message being read by a single `recv` in the client.  You might have to call `recv` repeatedly to read a single message.  Conversely, a single call to `recv` might return data from several calls to `write`.  You need to define a simple protocol and use that to decide how many messages have been received in the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution can be used if all messages are the same size. I don't know the size of your `message_replay`, lets just say its of type `char[256]`.

**At the server**

Instead of using `strlen()` you can always send 256 bytes. The client will just ignore all trailing characters after the null terminator.

```
write(sock , message_replay, 256); // or sizeof(message_replay) if it's static
```

**At the client**

Client should then expect all messages to be 256 bytes long. A loop runs untill all 256 characters have been received, and appends to `receive_buffer[]` every loop. Counters keep track of how many bytes we have received and how many we are short of.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NotEndOFList; i++) {
    char receive_buffer[256];
    int received_bytes = 0;
    int remaining_bytes = sizeof(receive_buffer);

    while (remaining_bytes > 0) {
        int res = recv(sock , &receive_buffer[received_bytes] , remaining_bytes, 0);
        if (res < 0) {
            puts("recv failed");
            break;
        }
        received_bytes += res;
        remaining_bytes -= res;
    }

    puts(receive_buffer);
}
```

PS! I've not tested, let me know how it runs if you decide to use it.

Comment: Btw, you should somehow check if receive_buffer really contains a null terminator char, or just add one at the end just to be sure. After the while loop, you can do `receive_buffer[sizeof(receive_buffer)-1] = '\0'`. If the server decides to send a message without a null terminator, the `puts()`-command won't know where to stop reading (it will probably stop when it starts to read from the memory area of `received_bytes`, which is too late.

Comment: I will try tomorrow and let you know thank you btw message_replay is same size